# Access Element in List by Index

Tags: dart

I'm getting this error while trying to access element in a `List` .

This is my code :

```
List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];

void _addCardWidgetExp() {
setState(() {
  widget.controllers.add(TextEditingController());
  widget.controllers.add(TextEditingController());
  widget.controllers.add(TextEditingController());
  widget.controllers.add(TextEditingController());

 

  _cardList.add(SizedBox(height: 10));
  Divider(
    thickness: 2,
    color: Colors.white,
  );
  _cardList.add(InputRefNomProduit(
    fieldController: widget.controllers.first,
    fieldController2: widget.controllers.[1],
    fieldController3: widget.controllers.[2],
    fieldController4: widget.controllers.last,
  ));
});
```

}

I'm getting the following error :

```
    The getter '[' isn't defined for the type 'List<TextEditingController>'.
Try importing the library that defines '[', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named '['.
```

ps: the error is only on these two lines :

```
fieldController2: widget.controllers.[1],
    fieldController3: widget.controllers.[2],
```

Comment: remove the dot in: `fieldController2: widget.controllers[1]` also in `fieldController3: widget.controllers[2]`

Comment: what a terrible error . Thank you .